# Multiple Dependant Dropdown boxes in a single django page

Tags: django

I have a specific need where I need to load drop boxes as per the selection made in the previous drop box. All in a single page.

Example:

```
Select the month : (12 Months in a drop down)
Select the shift : (Shifts shown in a drop box based on the selected Month)
Select the employee : (Employee list based on the selected Shift)
```

What is the Django's approach to this? Please help.

Note: I am yet to try anything on this as I find it difficult to get started.

Comment: Well if you want to do this without reloading( which you probably want), using django won't help you. You can use ajax to do this, which is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#month" ).change(function() {
    $.getJSON('/path/to/django/view/'+$('#month option:selected').val(), function(data) {
        $('#shift').empty();
        $('#shift').append('<option></option>');
        html="";
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            html+='<option value="'+key+'">'+val+'</option>';
        });
        $('#shift').append(html);
    });
});



urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    url(r'^/path/to/django/view/(?P<month>[^/]+)$', loadshift, name='loadshift'),
...
)



def loadshift(request,month):
    data=Shift.objects.filter(month=month).values_list('pk','name')
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict(data)), mimetype="application/json")
```